# How can I stream audio from a Windows PC to speakers connected to an AirPort Express?

Tags: windows-10, audio, airport-express

I'm running Windows 10 on a PC and I have an AirPort Express connected via Ethernet.

I can find and stream audio to the AirPort Express when using iTunes.

However, I often listen music on YouTube and would love to stream the audio through the AirPort Express.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A company called Rogue Amoeba makes a product called AirFoil, including a [Windows version](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/windows/), which supports streaming audio from any app to AirPort Express.

Note that AirPort Express audio streaming is buffered (read: delayed), so if this is for listening to music, you'll be fine. But it's not good for real time things like gaming or audio/video chat, and if you try to watch a video your audio will be way behind your video.